# Using Azure Active Directory B2C with NativeScript

Tags: azure, nativescript, azure-ad-b2c

Does [Azure Active Directory B2C](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/active-directory-b2c/) support any authentication mechanisms for mobile applications? I am planning to develop the application using NativeScript.

If not what is the best cross platform mobile framework to achieve authentication for Azure AD B2C?

Answer (score 3):

If you can integrate with azure mobile service. You can use the plugin 
https://github.com/PeterStaev/nativescript-azure-mobile-apps

Comment: This is using Azure mobile services and not Azure AD B2C. Do you have an implementation for that or any idea about a work flow?

Comment: I believe than AD can be integrated with azure mobile service. I didnt tried to implement.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to configure Azure Mobile Services using the Authentication/Authorization (Easy Auth) to use Azure AD B2C. Then using the nativescript-azure-mobile-apps plugin, it would open a Mobile Web View with a Login screen. Once I clicked the Register link, it allowed me to register and then redirected back to the phone with the JWT. Also, the login is fully working. There is just one problem. If I use the Cancel button in the Azure AD B2C page, the page states "Authorization is forbidden" with a white screen. Unfortunately, the Web View does not have a close button so the only way to get back to the app is using the phones back button. It can be confusing to the user.