# Authenticate using Azure AD B2C in a NativeScript angular Application

Tags: android, angular, mobile, nativescript, azure-ad-b2c

Are there plugins available to achieve Azure AD B2C authentication in a NativeScript angular Mobile application? I am trying to develop a mobile application for my existing Web Application that performs authentication using Azure AD B2C.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> Are there plugins available to achieve Azure AD B2C authentication in
> a NativeScript angular Mobile application?

Yes ,If you want to integrate with Azure mobile services using `NativeScript` angular application
with Azure AD B2C.

Here is the plugin: [GitHub| NativeScript Azure Mobile Apps plugin](https://github.com/PeterStaev/nativescript-azure-mobile-apps)

Please refer the below links for more information:

.[MS DOC |Enable authentication in your own Android app by using Azure AD B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/enable-authentication-android-app?tabs=kotlin)  & [Enable authentication in your own Angular Application by using Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/enable-authentication-angular-spa-app)

.[SO THREAD | Using Azure Active Directory B2C with NativeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41932805/using-azure-active-directory-b2c-with-nativescript) .